# nullpx in jasperreport html view

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I need a report in my web application.For that i have designed a jrxml in iReport. I had made a blank A4 template. And i had complied that file and then put that jrxml file to my classpath. But when i select that html view, an 'X' image is diplaying in that page. In view source, that element is given as

```
<td><img alt="" src="nullpx" style="width: 46px; height: 1px;"/></td>
```

My jsxml file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="myreport" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a086f896-d28c-413e-8acc-416ff16d190a">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="clientName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="currentBalance" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="creditLimit" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="bc001d2d-32f7-4222-8155-79f0ebd97aa3" x="26" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[clientName]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="15f41fea-5cad-43b4-809b-7285fb9fea9f" x="201" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[currentBalance]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="16d187cb-beb0-4799-bdcf-5bfdb1583626" x="416" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[creditLimit]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="38" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="2cf8baa2-d1bc-46e2-a194-422d8d967f38" x="26" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{clientName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="6c560e8a-8020-453c-9f5c-84cf9a964391" x="201" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{currentBalance}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d8d431d9-8be9-46fb-bb43-3f4583c9c9e2" x="416" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{creditLimit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Is there anyway that i can use html with out any images in htmlpage..

Answer (score 3):

Set JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN property to 'false'

Answer (score 3):

Set the `exporterParameter` named `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN` to `false`:

For example:

```
<bean id="multiViewReport" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsMultiFormatView">
    <property name="url" value="classpath:someJasperReport.jrxml" />
    <!-- Set the ModelMap attribute "reportDataKey" to the JRDataSourceProvider -->
    <property name="reportDataKey" value="reportDSProvider" /> 
    <property name="exporterParameters">
         <map>
             <entry
                key="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN">
                <value>false</value>
            </entry>
         </map>
     </property>
</bean>
```

and my controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/{format}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, @PathVariable(value = "format") String format) {
    JRDataSourceProvider jrDataSourceProvider = .....;
    model.addAttribute("format", format);
    model.addAttribute("reportDSProvider", jrDataSourceProvider);
    return "multiViewReport";
}
```

This controller allows me to produce different report formats by just appending the format type to the base url.

For example: http://yourhost.com:8080/springmvc-jasperreports/report/pdf

PS: I tested this with spring-webmvc 3.2.1.RELEASE and jasperreports 4.5.1.